# App Reload on Push Notification Click Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have implemented push notifications on my app and they work fine.
The problem I have is that when I click them in the pull down menu they immediately reload the app. To counter this I had the app create a new activity instance. This now opens a new page but when clicking back from this new page it has the same problem and reloads the whole app again.

I am using Xamarin Forms with PCL, so its not pure Android.
Is there a way to get the click event on the menu item to load a specific page view in PCL? Reloading the whole app is kind of useless.

This is the class the creates the phone notification:

ForegroundMessages.cs:

```
 [Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]

public class ForegroundMessages: FirebaseMessagingService
{


    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        //Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
        //Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);
        SendNotification(message.GetNotification().Body);
    }

    private void SendNotification(string body)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
       // var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + body);

        // sends notification to view model
        MessagingCenter.Send((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "Increase");

        Intent resultintent = new Intent(this,typeof(SecondActivity));

        TaskStackBuilder stackbuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
        stackbuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(SecondActivity)));
        stackbuilder.AddNextIntent(resultintent);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackbuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        var defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
            .SetContentTitle("Notification")
            .SetContentText(body)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
        notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }


}
```

and the Second Activity class:

```
  [Activity(Label = "Notifications")]
public class SecondActivity:Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("this worked");
    }

}
```

As stated, this works and receives messages fine and when you click them it loads second activity but when moving away from the second activity page it just reloads the whole app again.
It would be better if I could load a view page (.xaml or .xaml.cs) in the PCL rather than this.

Any ideas?

Comment: So I know why it reloads the whole app. By default it creates a new instance of main activity and therefore reloads the whole thing. So im going to use second activity as an intermediary to load a xaml page. I will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might check out [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43941497/3850012) which shows how I did it, I also open a Forms page. The post is kind of long but basically there are a few things:

- I do not use a second `Activity`
- I do not add the `ClearTop` flag to the `MainActivity` `Intent`
- I do not use the `TaskStackBuilder` and instead just use `PendingIntent.GetActivity` to get the `PendingIntent`
- Then I specifically address the app restart issue in the post by setting your `MainActivity`'s `LaunchMode` to `LaunchMode.SingleTop`, overriding `OnNewIntent` in your `MainActivity`, and then checking the `intent.HasExtras` for a special `string` that you set in your `SendNotification` method to distinguish that `Intent` from some other `Intent`

Let me know if you still have problems afterwards.

## Edit:

```
private void SendNotification(string body)
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
   // var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
    intent.PutExtra("SomeSpecialKey", "some special value");

    Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + body);

    if (Forms.IsInitialized) { // Ensure XF code has been initialized
        // sends notification to view model
        MessagingCenter.Send((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "Increase");
    }

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

    var defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
    var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
        .SetContentTitle("Notification")
        .SetContentText(body)
        .SetAutoCancel(true)
        .SetSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
    notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
}
```

Then in MainActivity:

```
[Activity(LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, ....)]
public class MainActivity : FormsApplicationActivity {

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        if(intent.HasExtra("SomeSpecialKey")) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\nIn MainActivity.OnNewIntent() - Intent Extras: " + intent.GetStringExtra("SomeSpecialKey") + "\n");
        }

        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Its the end of the day for me here, but I will check this out first thing tomorrow.

Comment: @user3355961 Sounds good. I will note that I am using the old GCM APIs and not the new Firebase ones but I do not think that the local Android Notification APIs are effected by that.

Comment: Hi, I have got i to hit the over ride intent in Main activity but im not sure how to pass it intent.HasExtra. What do I set in the send notification for it to trigger the HasExtra condition?

Comment: When I put a break point in Main Activity the intent is showing as having null extras

Comment: @user3355961 Correct. In your `SendNotification` method you are not adding any extras to your `MainActivity` `Intent`. So try adding `intent.PutExtra("some special key", "some special value");` Then you would look for `"some special key"` within `OnNewIntent`

Comment: I have tried something like that. I think its because I dont understand how PutExtra works. I have done this:
 `intent.PutExtra("LoadPage",1);`
Im not sure about that second parameter I tried using a boolean value as well with no affect.

Then within the on new intent:



` if (intent.HasExtra("LoadPage"))
    {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("works for new intetnt");
     }`

Comment: Its not formatting my code in the comment for some reason

Comment: Is PutExtra used within SendNotification or OnNewIntent?

Comment: @user3355961 See edit. For me I will add either the notification Id or the JSON of the notification to the PutExtra method's value. Also note that if you get a notification while the app is closed, your app will crash when it hits `MessagingCenter` line because XF code will not be available to you.

Comment: Hi, I have using putextras for navigate to specific page when click on push notification. I have 3 types of notifications, after getting three type of notifications when I am click on one of the type, it's only show the latest notification type related put extras in 'newintent' method. How can we save different type of notifications instead of one type. it's work fine only for one type of notification.

Comment: @Deepak The line that starts with `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity` in my example, you probably need to play with the flags being passed in. Try removing the `PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent` and then you might also need to pass unique integers in instead of using `0` like in my example.

Comment: this also works for Xamarin.Android ... thank you sir!  I've been searching forever and this was an awesome and thorough answer.  That was driving me crazy; whole app would go blank and I tried a bunch of stuff until I found this post.

Edit: the things that really did it were the `[Activity(LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, ....)]` and intent override

Answer (score 1):

Just add  `LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask` to your MainActivity